# Is it the case that for every matrix $A,B$, that if $AB=BA$, then $A=B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am currently studying Elementary Linear Algebra by Howard Anton (11th Edition), pg.30 True/False Exercises.

The question poses the statement that

if $AB=BA$, then $A$ must equal $B$

I would like to get some feedback on whether my argument is valid

Suppose

Matrix $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix and B is a $n\times m$ matrix

And

$AB = BA$

Then

$AB$ is a $m\times m$ matrix and $BA$ is a $n\times n$ matrix

Consider the case where $m\neq n$

Now

The amount of rows and columns of matrix $A$ and $B$ is not equal

So

The matrices does not have the same size

Therefore

It is not the case that $A=B$

Comment: You have not used an example where $AB=BA$

Comment: Consider two dimensional rotation matrices....

Comment: Take 1x1 matrices. Or any two nxn diagonal matrices.

Answer (score 5):

As already noted in comments, to disprove the claim "for all matrices $A,B$, if $AB=BA$ then $A=B$" it is sufficient to find two matrices $A,B$ such that $AB=BA$ but $A\ne B$. (Which is not what you did. You found that $AB=BA$ may not be true. However, we need to find the case where $AB=BA$ is true but $A=B$ is false.)

Examples of that are plentiful. If you like $1\times 1$ matrices, just take $[0][1]=[1][0]=[0]$ but $[0]\ne[1]$.

If not, you can generalize the above example to any size. If $0_n$ is the *zero* $n\times n$ matrix and $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ *identity* matrix, then:

- $0_nX=X0_n=0_n$ for any $n\times n$ matrix $X$, which may not be equal to $0_n$ (e.g., $X=I_n$).
- $I_nX=XI_n=X$ for any $n\times n$ matrix $X$, which may not be equal to $I_n$ (e.g., $X=0_n$).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Your answer helped point out where I think I went wrong.

Comment: I considered the case where the rows and columns of $AB$ and $BA$ are not equal, but I just contradicted my assumption that $AB=BA$, since they cannot be equal if their sizes are not equal.

Answer (score 2):

No for (roughly) the same reason it doesn't work in algebra (even if variables don't commute): $x x^2=x^2 x$, but $x\neq x^2$ in general.

You can actually pursue this example with matrices. Imagine the vector space $\Bbb R[x]/(x^3)$ with basis $1,x,x^2$. Multiplication by $x$ is a linear map with matrix representation

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

and multiplication by $x^2$ has

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

This isn't a super interesting example, but you can verify that $AB=BA$ is the zero matrix even though $A\neq B$.

Maybe a more straightforward example is just whenever $A$ and $B$ are inverse to one another. Then $AB=BA$ is the identity matrix, but generally $A\neq B$.

Answer (score 0):

A simplest counterexample I think is $A$ a unit square matrix, and $B$ arbitrary non-unit square matrix of the same dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head there are quite a few situations where $AB = BA$ but $A ≠ B$. The most obvious one to me is the case where $A$ is the identity matrix \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} and $B$ is anything but the identity matrix, let’s say for example $B$ is \begin{bmatrix}2&9&8\\1&3&5\\2&4&7\end{bmatrix} In such a case, $AB = BA = \begin{bmatrix}2&9&8\\1&3&5\\2&4&7\end{bmatrix}$ but it is obvious that \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} ≠ \begin{bmatrix}2&9&8\\1&3&5\\2&4&7\end{bmatrix}